# check substring exists in a dictionary value during iteration

Tags: python, dictionary

Below code is working fine , but can anyone guide how to simplify this.
newrelicid is a dictionary where it contains 'number' as key and 'some string' as value  (string can contain substrings like prod,test,local etc
)
Basically I am trying to ignore the values ( j ) that contains substring from the list `['dev','staging','qat','uat','local','eu']`

sample newrelicid value

```
{1: 'Service PROD', 2: 'service', 3: 'guess-service (Production)', 4: 'check-service (Dev)', 5: 'analytics-service (Staging)' }
```

loop:

```
for i,j in newrelicid.items():
  if 'staging' not in j.lower() and not 'qat' in j.lower() and not 'uat' in j.lower() and not 'local' in j.lower() and not 'eu' in j.lower() and not 'dev' in j.lower():
    print(j)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `any()` to effectively mimic a nested iteration:

```
>>> newrelicid = {
...     1: 'Service PROD',
...     2: 'service',
...     3: 'guess-service (Production)',
...     4: 'check-service (Dev)',
...     5: 'analytics-service (Staging)'
... }
>>> blacklist = {'dev','staging','qat','uat','local','eu'}

>>> {v for v in newrelicid.values()
...     if not any(i in v.casefold() for i in blacklist)}
{'Service PROD', 'guess-service (Production)', 'service'}
```

This produces a `set[str]` of the passed values.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression:

```
import re

pattern = r'staging|local|uat|qat|dev|eu' # one pattern for all keywords

newrelicid = {1: 'Service PROD', 2: 'service', 3: 'guess-service (Production)',
              4: 'check-service (Dev)', 5: 'analytics-service (Staging)' }

for j in newrelicid.values():
    if re.search(pattern,j.lower()): # match with lowercase
        print(j)

check-service (Dev)
analytics-service (Staging)
```

You could improve the pattern if what you need are whole words and not merely substrings:

```
pattern = r'\b(staging|local|uat|qat|dev|eu)\b'
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to apply a filter.

By the way, since you are only looking at the strings in your dictionaty, use dict.values()

```
l = ['staging','qat', 'uat', 'local', 'eu', 'dev']

list(filter(lambda x : not any(e in x.lower() for e in l),  newrelicid.values()))

['Service PROD', 'service', 'guess-service (Production)']
```

Comment: Thanks Marco , is ther anyway i can add one more condition  `if 'worker' in ` along with the lines you shared

Comment: I am not sure I understand this, can you explain better? a condition to what?

Comment: `{v for v in newrelicid.values()  if not any(i in v.casefold() for i in blacklist) and 'worker' in v }` i have added one more condition `worker in v` with the brad solomon answer , similarly i am looking for how to achieve from  your script

Comment: sure you can add as many conditions to the lambda function as you want. The idea of `filter` is that if the expression after `:` in the lambda function evaluates to True, then the element is kept in the output list